# Makefile not creating objects with multiple sources

Tags: c++, c, makefile, compilation, gnu-make

I'm triying to write a makefile that can take any amount of sources dirs and create their object files in a tidy way. I found [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1181546) post that tries more or less the same, I'm at the point that the object dirs are created correctly. But getting the `make: *** No rule to make target` error when triying to create the objects.

This is my makefile at the moment

```
INCLUDES =  -I includes/    \
            -I  mlx

EXECPT_DIRS =   /mlx

OBJDIR      =   objs
SRCDIR      =   src

SRCDIRS     :=  $(shell find . -name '*.c'  -exec dirname {} \;| uniq | sed 's/\/$(SRCDIR)//g' | sed 's/\$(EXECPT_DIRS)//g' | cut -d . -f 2)
SRCS        :=  $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -name '*.c')
OBJS        :=  $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)%.c,$(OBJDIR)%.o, $(SRCS))

#############################################

#.SILENT:
all: $(NAME)

$(NAME) : buildtree $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) libraries/*

$(OBJDIR)%.o: $(SRCDIR)%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@
clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR)

fclean: clean
    $(RM) $(NAME)

re: fclean all

buildtree:
    @$(call mk_dir)

define mk_dir
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)/;        \
    for dir in $(SRCDIRS);  \
    do  \
        mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)/$$dir;   \
    done
endef

.PHONY: all clean fclean re bonus ext
```

My tree before `make`
looks like this:

```
├── includes
├── libraries
├── mlx
│   └── man
│       └── man3
└── src
    ├── 42lib
    └── cub3d
```

after

```
.
├── includes
├── libraries
├── mlx
│   └── man
│       └── man3
├── objs
│   ├── 42lib
│   └── cub3d
└── src
    ├── 42lib
    └── cub3d
```

I did manage to get the object created using this makefile from the post:

```
APP     = Hello

SRCDIR  = Sources
OBJDIR  = Objects

SRCS    := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -name '*.c')
SRCDIRS := $(shell find . -name '*.c' -exec dirname {} \; | uniq)
OBJS    := $(patsubst %.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))

CFLAGS  = -Wall -pedantic -ansi
LDFLAGS =


all: $(APP)

$(APP) : buildrepo $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS)

distclean: clean
    $(RM) $(APP)

buildrepo:
    @$(call make-repo)

define make-repo
   for dir in $(SRCDIRS); \
   do \
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)/$$dir; \
   done
endef
```

But the objects got created in the objs/src/*dir* instead of objs/*dir* and it relinked too.
Some help with the relink would be really appreciated :)

Comment: You don't provide enough info.  First, please show the full error message: _which_ target did `make` say it didn't know how to make?  Second, it's hard to see from your scripting here exactly what happens: I recommend you add `$(info SRCS=$(SRCS))` and ditto for `OBJS` so you can see the value of those variables.  Do they look right?

Comment: the values look totally right to me, every SRC in his path finished in .c and the OBJS where should be created. The full error is this one `make: *** No rule to make target 'objs/42lib/ft_isnot_empty_str.o', needed by 'cub3d'.  Stop.` where cub3d is NAME and ft_isnot_empty_str.o the first file of each SRCS and OBJS vars

Comment: I'm assuming that the file `src/42lib/ft_isnot_empty_str.c` does exist?  I recommend you add slashes to your rule; change: `$(OBJDIR)%.o: $(SRCDIR)%.c` to `$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c` and see if that helps.

Comment: It looks overly complicated.  Why are you using $(shell find ..) instead of wildcards (or at all)?

Comment: Non-file targets should be listed as .PHONY.  Consider restricting yourself to the standard targest https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Standard-Targets.html if others use your make file. buildrepo should probably an order-only prerequisite.   This adds over-head on every build so to me makes more sense to just make it part of your src tree.  Use the the build-in catalog instead of writing all the rules out.

Comment: And if you don't know, you can use VPATH to tell make to search for files in certain directories.